# GitLab /bin/sh: eval: line 142: git: not found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - test
  - deploy

deploy-test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - /^B[Ii]-.*$/
  script:
     - . PublishPBIReports.sh

deploy-prod:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  only:
    - master
  script:
     - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

sh files contain this code:

```
pbifiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 -- '***.pbix')
for pbifile in $pbifiles
do
    python UploadPBITest.py --files $pbifile
done
```

But when my pipeline starts, i got this error:
Using docker image sha256:5f3d65aad428d30878e893e86ddfd74979979b0d2a03894069bab1b118a73370 for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:7dad83861f0b28bd6a0b281dc5f72144927b9f8173e388e461c8feba6be20bec ...

$ pbifiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 -- '***.pbix') # collapsed multi-line command

/bin/sh: eval: line 142: git: not found

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127

Comment: The image on which you run your jobs, `docker:latest`, doesn’t have `git` installed.

Comment: how can i add git in image? when runner starting, he copy all repository, right? Sorry for maybe stupid question, i'm new to this

Comment: Either you install it as part of the job; the `docker` image looks like it’s based on Alpine, so `apk add --no-cache git`. Or you specify some other image for the job; `image: …`.

Comment: Maybe it's stupid question, but i should add this (apk add --no-cache git) on sh file or my job? @Biffen

Comment: Either should work. If the script is meant to be used outside CI/CD then it might be a better idea to put it in the job. But note that this will install Git _every time_ the job runs, so your pipelines will be slower. The ‘correct’ thing would be to use some other image with Git pre-installed, perhaps one you build yourself.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks. Early i added code to script block, like:

  script:
     - apk add --no-cache git
     - . PublishPBIReports.sh

but it didn't work, i got same error git not found